# Will BotFramework-CLI support Azure's new Question Answering service?

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker, nlp-question-answering

Now that [Azure's Question Answering](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/question-answering) service is available and we are recommended to migrate from QnA Maker, I noticed that [botframework-cli](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli) does not seem to have been updated and I did not see any issues or information related to it being updated to support authoring Knowledge Bases for the new **Question Answering** service. Our CI/CD pipelines use these CLI tools to create/update/delete Knowledge Bases.

It seems the only way to automate this is via the [Authoring REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/authoring), is that true? If so, is there any rough ETA on when that might be updated or some other CLI tool will be made available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no support to manage project creation (a.k.a. knowledgebases) within Question Answer from BotFramework-cli. They do however offer a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/quickstart/sdk?pivots=rest), and SDK support with [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/quickstart/sdk?pivots=programming-language-csharp) and [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/quickstart/sdk?pivots=programming-language-python).

There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/issues/1340) to support this, but from Apr. 19, 2022 to Sept. 19, 2022 there has been no response nor update.

Answer (score 1):

THe next SDK release of Bot Framework supports this new feature. https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/6413
Not sure if the cli tools are in scope. If not, I suggest you enter a feature request [in that repository](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/issues)

Comment: Thanks, that's good to hear! I did open up an [issue on the CLI repo](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/issues/1339) for Orchestrator support since that's a much, much bigger issue for us that can't be worked around like this one can.

Comment: Created [an issue in that repo](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/issues/1340) for this question, I'll update this question hopefully when I get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear documentation on migration procedure of QnA maker to azure question answering. Please do check the below mentioned link and follow the steps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/migrate-qnamaker

The services are updated in May 2021 itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I did read that before asking and unfortunately the documentation doesn't contain anything about botframework-cli and I went and checked the github and it doesn't either